# ImageJ macro to run through folder, merging three images at the time, skips one image during first iteration

Tags: for-loop, image-processing, batch-processing, imagej, fiji

I am making a script to merge channels together into a 4D stack. It should take three images in a folder at a time, merge them, and save the composite image.

What I don't understand is that in the first iteration, it skips the 3rd image (opening only the first two), and then starts the next iteration with the third image. So only the first iteration is wrong, but it's not like it skips the first image all together.

```
// Specify the directory containing the images
dir = getDirectory("Select a directory");
output = dir + "Merged" + File.separator; 
File.makeDirectory(output);

// Get a list of all the files in the directory
list = getFileList(dir);

// Loop through the list of files, three at a time
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 3) {
    if (endsWith(list[i], ".tif")) {
        open(dir + list[i]);
    }

    if (i + 1 < list.length) {
        if (endsWith(list[i + 1], ".tif")) {
            open(dir + list[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    if (i + 2 < list.length) {
        if (endsWith(list[i + 2], ".tif")) {
            open(dir + list[i + 2]);
        }
    }
    
    // Get name of the image without channel number
    imageName = substring(getTitle(), 0, (lengthOf(getTitle())-9));
    imageList = getList("image.titles");
    Array.sort(imageList);
    
    // Merge the channels and save
    run("Merge Channels...", "c1=" + imageList[0] + " c2=" + imageList[1] + " c7=" + imageList[2]);
    rename(imageName + "_merged");
    
    saveAs("Tiff", output + getTitle() + ".tif");
    close("*");
}
```

After replacing the merge channel command by a print array command and waitForUser, I could see it opens image 1, 2, prompts a waitForUser, opens 3, 4, 5, prompts a waitForUser, etc etc..

I feel the mistake I made is minor, but I cant seem to find it..

Comment: I think you increment your loop counter even if the filename doesn't end in `.tif`, whereas you should only count the files you actually use... maybe.

Comment: That makes sense. A 'dirty' way around this I can think of would be to index the image names first (rather than the whole file list), and then use that to open images a bit more directly, eg by taking the first three names of that list and opening those, then repeat etc..

Would there be a more elegant way of doing it?

Edit: more specifically, is there a more elegant way of having a loop increment skipping all but .tif files?

Comment: Sorry, I don't even recognise what language that is!

Comment: It is the ImageJ macro language. Syntax is like that of Java and the available functions are listed here: <https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html> (No fun checking the OP's code...)

Comment: You can easily check if the indexing is the problem, by creating a new folder where you only have tifs. In any case, you should increase the counter only when opening a tif (like @MarkSetchell already said). That would probably be easier with a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the answer could possibly be this simple... but I noticed that here :

// Merge the channels and save
run("Merge Channels...", "c1=" + imageList[0] + " c2=" + imageList[1] + " c7=" + imageList[2]);
rename(imageName + "_merged");

you have written c1, c2, and then c7... I tried running this on my own images (also in sets of three), and changed c7 to c3, and now it seems to be working :P

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late of an answer but, I was encountering the issue that only two files would open and it seemed to be skipping the first "open" command completely.

After playing around for a while, I got to open three files but only when I had 4 interations of "if ... open" listed.
After some more playing around I made the small change detailed below and this got it opening all three files, with only 3 open commands do some renaming and saving of files and then open up the next 3 files in the list and repeat:

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i +=3) {           //Adjust += number to appropriate number of channels
file = list[i];
if (i < list.length) {
    if (file.endsWith(".tif")) {
        open(dir+file);
    }
}
if (i + 1 < list.length) {
    if (file.endsWith(".tif")) {
        open(dir + list[i + 1]);
    }
}
if (i + 2 < list.length) {
    if (file.endsWith(".tif")) {
        open(dir + list[i + 2]);
    }
}
```

and so on for I'm guessing however many channels you want.

I can not state just how much your code helped me!
I'm fairly new to fiji macro-ing and have been trying the entire time to figure out how to get multiple tif files to open together.

Hope this helps, and again massive thanks for code that opens multiple files!